# Text doesn't change on frame 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5

Hi I'm new to flash programming so please bear with me if this sounds like a bit too junior a question to someone in the Flash area.

I've dragged a Text Tool from the panel to Stage and named the instance "status". Then I typed in "ABC" into the Text Tool. In frame 1 on the timeline I typed in the following code:

```
status.text = "Hello";
status.color = 0x0000FF;
```

The problem is that text in the status doesn't seem to change and remain "ABC". The color also doesn't change to the specified one, although if I delete the second line of code, I wouldn't be able to see the text at all (it seems the color gets to white which is the same as the background?)

Could someone please give me some guidance?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

Changing color of dynamic text in flash cannot be done using "color" instead use "textColor"

```
status.text="hello"
status.textColor=0xff0000
```

This will also solve your problem of the text not changing

I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up Asta. I tried the code you mentioned above but unfortunately the problem remained. An interesting thing I noted but didn't understand was that the text kept flickering from the beginning.

Comment: OK , can you please tell me the exact code that you wrote?

Comment: The exact code was all listed i the issue - only two lines. If you have a couple of minutes to try the steps I mentioned in the IDE I believe you could repro the issue as well. I just recreated a fresh new AS file and and repeated the steps and the problem reproed again...

Comment: I have wrote the same code that I told you in the IDE and it worked perfecly

Comment: Can you tell me the exact problem?

Comment: Could I send my AS file directly to you to take a look? It only contains two lines of code. My email is 1916410110 at qq dot com. thanks very much...

Comment: Look, right now I am not home so I can't view the file but if you can , Can you take a screen shot of it ? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117679/discussion-between-jack-x-and-asta).